# FileZilla remote server or website is not updating

Tags: asp.net, web, remote-server, ftp-client, filezilla

I'm using FileZilla FTP Client while editing my website but seems like it's not updating on the server. I tried many times editing and replacing the old files, then visiting my website but nothing changed. I already cleared out my browser cache, history, everything, still no changes at all. I'm stuck.

I also tried deleting default.asp, then visited the website. I'm expecting default.asp will not appear, but default.asp is still accessible. I don't know why.

In FileZilla, it always gives me that the command is successful. But again nothing happens. Hoping someone would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try recycling the app-pool where the website is running on. Might be that the cache of the webserver not showing you the changes.

Comment: where i can find the app-pool? thanks for your reply

Comment: I reckon you have access to the server the website runs on. Go to the IIS manager on that server, go to App Pools, search for the Default App Pool, or the app pool the website runs under, right click, and select Recycle.